# Python Запись из файла в 2-ух мерный массив

Tags: python, массивы, матрицы

Пишу калькулятор матриц. Столкнулся с проблемой. Необходимо реализовать запись из txt файла в двумерный массив, для произведения дальнейших операций. В txt фале хранится матрица следующего вида:

> х  х  х
>
> х  х  х
>
> х  х  х

(число столбцов равно числу строк)

Мой код:

```
import numpy as np

Z =  np.array(open(r'Z.txt'))

print(z)
```

После запуска этого кода python 3.5.1 выдает следующую ошибку:

> <_io.TextIOWrapper name='Z.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1251'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для чтения данных из текстовых файлов в numpy есть функция [loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). В простейшем случае достаточно

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt(fname)
```